# Reusing the same page multiple times

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml, include

Is it possible to reuse one page multiple times attached to different objects?

I have a page were you can input personal information (name, address, social number, ...) connect to one bean: prospect.
In some occasions I must gather linked personal information. example for credit scoring (a person and a guarantor).

So I wanted to use  with 2 includes. But how can I make sure include1 holds the information for person1 and include2 holds the information for person2?

```
<rich:tabPanel id="creditScoreTab" switchType="client" >
  <rich:tab id="mainContractor" >
    <ui:include src="includes/prospect.xhtml" />
  </rich:tab>
  <rich:tab id="guarantor">
    <ui:include src="includes/prospect.xhtml" />
  </rich:tab>
</rich:tabPanel>
```

and facescontext

```
<managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>prospect</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>be.foo.Prospect</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

I found 2 possible work arounds:
-duplicate the page and define 2 beans in faces-config (pointing to the same java class) 
-do not use tabpanel and  include, but enter person1 info , then save it and load person2 info and save person2.

Workaround1 negative point is that it is maintaining the same code twice. Workaround2 negative point is that it is not so 'cool' (ux point of view)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`<ui:param>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/param.html) to pass parameters to [`<ui:include>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/include.html):

```
<rich:tabPanel id="creditScoreTab" switchType="client" >
  <rich:tab id="mainContractor" >
    <f:subview id="mainContractorView">
      <ui:include src="includes/prospect.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="person" value="#{bean.person1}" />
      </ui:include>
    </f:subview>
  </rich:tab>
  <rich:tab id="guarantor">
    <f:subview id="guarantorView">
      <ui:include src="includes/prospect.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="person" value="#{bean.person2}" />
      </ui:include>
    </f:subview>
  </rich:tab>
</rich:tabPanel>
```

With the above example, in each include the desired person will be available as `#{person}`. Those `<f:subview>` tags are to prevent duplicate component ID errors because they end up within the same `UINamingContainer` parent.

Comment: When I do this I get the following error:javax.servlet.ServletException: Component ID prospectdetail:creditScoreView:privatePerson has already been found in the view.    How can I solve this? privatePerson is a component id used in prospect.xhtml

Comment: Apparently the RichFaces tabs are no `UINamingContainer` components. Try putting `<f:subview>` with an unique ID around the `<ui:include>`.